# Is it possible to "return" a function from another function?

Tags: go

Due the verbose error handling syntax I've created a function `check` as below which acts as a "global" error handler. If I want to  panic instead to log I change only the `check` function. The issue is that now I want to simply `return`  so that the other go routines can still run if one has an error. So the question is: How can I do that ? Is it possible?

```
func main() {
    for k, v := range foo {
        go func() {
            err = doSomething()
            check("this one failed", err)
        }()
    }
}

func check(errMsg string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(errMsg, err)
    }
}
```

However now I've found that I need  return the anonymous function if there is any error rather than exit ( `log.Fatal` ) so I'm wondering if it's possible to return the anyonymou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a language feature that allows you to cause the parent function to automatically return in response to a simple function call.

However, there is a way to cause the current goroutine to exit, which might be what you are after: [`runtime.Goexit`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit).  Note that this has similar disruptive potential to calling `os.Exit`, so it would be bad to call it in the context of goroutines created by other packages or other unrelated code.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your check function returns a `bool`:

```
func checkIfFailed(errMsg string, err error) bool {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf(errMsg, err)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

That way, you can still call your check (and do all kind of checks in it), while returning early from the anonymous function:

```
err = doSomething()
if checkIfFailed("this one failed", err) {
    return
}
```

Comment: any reason to do not return the other way around ( false if there is  not an error and true if there is an error ) ? I assume I save one keystroke (`!`)

Comment: @hey sure, but in that case, I had to change the function name ;)